# Openresty: Manually refreshing the id token without refreshing the session token?

Tags: openresty, lua-resty-openidc

I was looking at the readme at https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc and I saw that there was a `refresh_session_interval` option which supposedly "refreshes the users id_token after X seconds without requiring re-authentication".

This works for our situation but I was wondering if there was some config or option so that we could manually trigger that refresh ourselves instead of passively waiting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it isn't possible yet to request a new id token so we went with a different solution.